# Join two tables and select record(table2) to form(table1) with drop-down-select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, join, activerecord

I would like to join two tables I have a table 'persons' and a table 'factories'.

My question is, how can I add a person and than choose (with a dropdown) the factory the person belongs to?

My persons model:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :factories

  has_attached_file :cv

  attr_accessible :cv, :email, :function, :mobile, :telephone
end
```

My factories model:

```
class Factory < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :persons

  attr_accessible :last_name, :email, :telephone, :first_name, :website, :country
end
```

I want to do it for example:

---

| Add Person |

Function: (input field)

Telephone: (input field)

Mobile: (input field)

Email: (input field)

Factory (Drop-down) <= this is the actual field i would like to have and it is not placed in the persons table by default.

CV: (upload field)

Submit: (submit button)

---

I hope you understand what i would like to have and i hope someone could help.

---

**EDIT 1
I changed my plans. I would like to have a chosen factory.id in a column in the persons table.

I made a column in my Person table with the name factory.id now I would to to store the data from the other table in that column.
Is this possible?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably do this:

Controller:

```
@people=Person.new

@factories = Factory.all
```

View:

```
    form_for @people do |a|
.
.
.
    = a.select :factory, options_for_select(@factories.map{ |f| [f.name, f.id] })
```

Comment: i had no time to try it, today i'm going to try

Comment: the answer from iwiznia worked but it's a select_tag i would like to have it like f.select or a.select. how do i do that?

Comment: I get the error undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass when i try your code. why is this?

Comment: If you are doing @ factories.map and getting this error.
I feel @ factories is not populated.
Run it in rails console and check.

Comment: i fixed it :) i used this in my view.  <%= f.select :factories, options_for_select(@factory.map{ |f| [f.name, f.id] }), :include_blank => true %>
and some changes in my controller. Thanks this worked out better than the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't choose the factory with a dropdown because the Person has_many factories... 
You could do it in the other direction, when you create a Factory you can select the Person it belongs_to with a dropdown.
If you want to do it like you said, you could have a dropdown with multi select enabled, and process that on the controller by hand, doing something like:

```
@person =  Person.create(params[:person])
params[:factories].each do |f|
  @person.factories << Factory.find(f)
end
```

In you view:

```
select_tag("factories", options_from_collection_for_select(Factory.all, "id", "name"), {:multiple => true})
```

Comment: Using the select_tag helper, it should look something like:
   select_tag("factories", options_from_collection_for_select(Factory.all, "id", "name"), {:multiple => true})

Comment: Allright thanks, i will try it tommorrow, thanks for you help

Comment: I'm not sure if I get it, so it's not: person: has_many factories?

Comment: the thing is. i would like to store an id from another table into my persons table so you can select which factory belongs to which person and could you give me an example code about how to do this with f.select? instead of select_tag thanks